# F5 vs Windows Network Load Balancer

Tags: windows, load-balancing

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 for deployment of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013. I can use F5 as its available.

I want to know the criteria for deciding F5 or Network Load Balancing. Which is better in which condition. Its an intranet setup. I might be using HTTPS/SSL in future, right now using HTTP. I do not need sticky session.

I read few blogs but they are older and might not provide the comparison of current capabilities in Windows inbuilt Load Balancing vs F5 BIG-IP.

Please let me know in case any specific information is required from my end. References are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to find any metric where Windows Network Load Balancing would lose out to an F5 - with the exception of cost and maybe ease of management.

But, if you've got a real Load Balancer sat there ready to use then I can't imagine any reason for not using it.

Comment: I have implemented Windows NLB and looking if there is any drawback/performance overhead in not using F5. F5 is being purchased for other systems but not configured yet.